# I want to keep the user information during user registration even after reloading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry, this is not a code question.

I'm currently working on a web application using React.

I've been using **Redux** to manage user registration information (ex: email address, etc.) for user registration over several pages, but I noticed that the registered information disappears after reloading.

I thought about saving the information to `localStorage`, but gave up due to the security risk.

How would you guys keep your users' registration information?

Comment: Who are these users registering with?

Comment: "*gave up due to the security risk*" - what security risk? What data does your application (need to) use, and against what do you need to protect this data? Actually localstorage is more secure than sending out the data over the internet in many cases.

Comment: You can persist data wherever you like.  Local storage only stores data on the user's computer, so if you're worried about the user controlling that data then you'd probably want to store data server-side.  A database is a common choice.

Comment: This is a web application that I am working on. It's not finished yet, so I haven't released it to the public.

Comment: @Maru You already wrote that it's a "web application", but that's really meaningless as it only describes some technology and doesn't tell us what the application does. (Also from what you told, it appears it's currently more like a static webpage, not an application).

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations!
I am not good at English, so i might give you some trouble.
I've heard that keeping personal information in localstorage can be dangerous, like XSS (Cross-Site Scripting). So, I am hesitant to install it.

Comment: I thought about implementing a database, but I would like to retain the final information of the user after the registration is complete.

(I don't want to retain the information of users who quit their registration in the middle of the process.)

This is why I am hesitant to implement a database.

Comment: Of course, I am using the database for user information that has been registered.

Comment: In order to describe a "web application," should I describe the technology I'm using?
I'm using create-react-app to create a single page application.
I'm using firebase for the backend and no server management.

Comment: @Maru: So what exactly is the problem, then?  If you don't want to persist the information to the server until the entire process is complete, but want to keep it available on the client in the meantime, then that's what local storage is for.  "I've heard it can be dangerous" is a non-starter.  What specific problem are you expecting from this?  If you have some values that you want the browser to remember on a page refresh then local storage is the tool you're looking for.  The data is visible to the user, but this is data that was *just entered by* that user, so they already know it.

Comment: @Maru Thanks, "firebase for the backend" is the key here. But like David, I don't really understand the problem. When the user successfully registers, you store their data in your firebase; until they do so you either keep it locally in the page, or in the session storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the information is not much, you could use encrypted cookie data, and read back the data on page load.

1. Create a `.env` file in your project root folder
2. Save your pass access in this file like so `REACT_APP_PASS=8604460484466`
3. use a function like

```
    const encryptWithAES = (text, pass) => {
      const passphrase = pass;
      return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, passphrase).toString();
    }; // remember to import CryptoJS
```

4. When the page loads you can read the data with:

```
    export const decryptWithAES = (ciphertext, pass) => {
      const passphrase = pass;
      const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, passphrase);
      const originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
      return originalText;
    };
```

5. When you want to store the cookie, then you can do it like so:

```
const tobeStored = encryptWithAES('text to encrypt', process.env.REACT_APP_PASS);
// then store it in your cookie.
```

6. When you want to retrieve it:

```
const cookieData = someGetCookieFunction('UserInfo');
const decrypted  = decryptWithAES(cookieData,process.env.REACT_APP_PASS);
```

7. I am assuming that you know how to read cookie from your script.

[See more information here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) and [Here As well](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) on how to set and call environment variables.

Comment: Encrypt using what key? Please be specific - the usefulness and security of this scheme hinges around that question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Do you mean that the information is encrypted when the cookie is registered, and the encryption is decrypted when it is retrieved?

Comment: Yes, use the first function to encrypt the data and when you retrieve it, you can decrypt it using same pass

Comment: I understand! Is there a general method of encryption?

Comment: Actually no, it depends on the programmer and what he wants to do.

Comment: I see! What are the most common methods?

Comment: My app will temporarily hold the user's email address, password, etc. (until the user registration is complete). I prefer to avoid anything that is too risky.

Comment: I understand, the safest way is to encrypt the data like the answer suggested. You can rewrite the functions to suite your needs, I basically picked them from my code.

Comment: Since the encryption key is public, this will not stop a dedicated attacker. It's at best obfuscation of the data, not encryption with a secret.